# How to fetch data from an api in React Native from Django rest framework using axios

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

This is the context Provider That has my state that is fetched from the rest framework api.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const PostContext = createContext();

const PostContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/')
            .then(res => {
                setPosts(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }, []);


 return(

    <PostContext.Provider value={{ posts }}>
        {props.children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  
  )
}


export default PostContextProvider**
```

When I try to console log it I get an this error in my emulator console.log

```
 Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["[]"]}
Array []
```

When I check my browser, I got this error.

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I tried to configure my backend using cors headers and the code looks like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
    # 'rest_framework_filters',
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'cart.apps.CartConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    
    # CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    #     'http://localhost:19002/'
    # )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't created any static files ( js or css ) in your django repo then comment out

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

or in setting `STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

gussing this after showing your error. This might help!